# Write extra string into excel file with byte[] getting error

Tags: c#, .net

For some reasons, I want to write a GUID as ID into one file for save, and delete the id before opening the file.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string id = "b669fd8c904d48e0945c16cac1dc5ed9";
        byte[] idbyte = UnicodeEncoding.Default.GetBytes(id);

        FileStream input = new FileStream(@"C:\test.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        FileStream output = new FileStream(@"C:\test1.xlsx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        CopyStream(input, output);
        // add id with byte[] at the end of the file
        output.Write(idbyte, 0, idbyte.Length);
        output.Close();
        input.Close();

        FileStream input1 = new FileStream(@"C:\test1.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        FileStream output1 = new FileStream(@"C:\test2.xlsx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        int SizeOfBuffer = 1024 * 16;
        try
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[SizeOfBuffer];
            byte[] bufferLast = new byte[SizeOfBuffer];
            int read;
            int Nextread;
            while ((read = input1.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {

                if ((Nextread = input1.Read(bufferLast, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output1.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    output1.Write(bufferLast, 0, Nextread);
                }
                else   // delete id with byte[] 
                {

                    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[SizeOfBuffer];
                    for (int i = 0; i < read - idbyte.Length; i++)
                    {
                        buffer2[i] = buffer[i];
                    }
                    output1.Write(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length);
                    break;
                }

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        output1.Close();
        input1.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

  private static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        int SizeOfBuffer = 1024 * 16;
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[SizeOfBuffer];
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But when I open the C:\test2.xlsx, excel shows error: "Excel found unreadable content in 'test2.xlsx'"!

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: ..you're attempting to hack the Excel file format and expect Excel to be fine with your changes afterwards?

Comment: Not so . i want to  encrypt a file,add a guid as id for  encrypted file,then my app will identify Depending on id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me.  As you can see I did a bit of reorganizing so I could more easily tell what I was doing and to simplify the tests.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
class Program
{
    private const int SIZE_OF_BUFFER = 1024 * 16;
    private const string FILE_PATH_ORIGINAL = @"C:\test.xlsx",
                        FILE_PATH_WithId = @"C:\test1.xlsx",
                        FILE_PATH_IdRemoved = @"C:\test2.xlsx";

    private static readonly byte[] idbyte = UnicodeEncoding.Default.GetBytes("b669fd8c904d48e0945c16cac1dc5ed9");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddGuidToFile(FILE_PATH_ORIGINAL, FILE_PATH_WithId);
        RemoveGuidToFile(FILE_PATH_WithId, FILE_PATH_IdRemoved);
        CompairFiles(FILE_PATH_ORIGINAL, FILE_PATH_IdRemoved);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void AddGuidToFile(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE_OF_BUFFER];
        FileStream input = new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
                    output = new FileStream(destinationFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        int read;

        try
        {
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)   //Copy source file to destination file.
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            output.Write(idbyte, 0, idbyte.Length);                     //Add guid to the end of the destination file.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close files
            input.Close();
            output.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveGuidToFile(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
    {
        byte[] currentBuffer = new byte[SIZE_OF_BUFFER],
                nextBuffer = new byte[SIZE_OF_BUFFER],
                tempBuffer;
        FileStream input = new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
                    output = new FileStream(destinationFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        int currentRead,
            nextRead = 0;                                       //Initialize to 0 incase file's lenght is less then SizeOfBuffer.

        try
        {
            currentRead = input.Read(currentBuffer, 0, currentBuffer.Length);   //Get first chunk.
            if (currentRead == currentBuffer.Length)                            //If first chunck is a full buffer then loop until it is not.
            {
                nextRead = input.Read(nextBuffer, 0, nextBuffer.Length);

                while (nextRead > idbyte.Length)
                {
                    output.Write(currentBuffer, 0, currentRead);                //Since nextBuffer is large enough to contain the ID, write the current buffer out.

                    //Swap buffers.
                    tempBuffer = currentBuffer;
                    currentBuffer = nextBuffer;
                    nextBuffer = tempBuffer;

                    //Update counts and fill next buffer.
                    currentRead = nextRead;
                    nextRead = input.Read(nextBuffer, 0, nextBuffer.Length);
                }
            }

            currentRead += nextRead - idbyte.Length;                            //Update currentRead to be the number of bytes in the buffer which are not part of the ID.

            output.Write(currentBuffer, 0, currentRead);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close files
            input.Close();
            output.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void CompairFiles(string originalFilePath, string idRemovedFilePath)
    {
        byte[] originalBuffer = new byte[SIZE_OF_BUFFER],
                idRemovedBuffer = new byte[SIZE_OF_BUFFER];
        FileStream original = new FileStream(originalFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
                    idRemoved = new FileStream(idRemovedFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        int originalRead,
            idRemovedRead;

        try
        {
            do
            {
                originalRead = original.Read(originalBuffer, 0, originalBuffer.Length);
                idRemovedRead = idRemoved.Read(idRemovedBuffer, 0, idRemovedBuffer.Length);

                if (originalRead != idRemovedRead) { throw new Exception("Error: file sizes do not match.  originalRead = " + originalRead + ", idRemovedRead = " + idRemovedRead + ", SIZE_OF_BUFFER = " + SIZE_OF_BUFFER); }

                for (int i = 0; i < originalRead; i++)
                {
                    if (originalBuffer[i] != idRemovedBuffer[i]) { throw new Exception("Error: file contents do not match.  i = " + i + ",inputBuffer[i] = " + originalBuffer[i] + ", idRemovedBuffer[i] = " + idRemovedBuffer[i]); }
                }
            }
            while (originalRead == idRemovedRead && originalRead > 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close files
            original.Close();
            idRemoved.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: open the file still get erro

Comment: Ok, I will test it tonight.

Comment: @okqin I have updated my answer.  This works for me.  There is also a test at the end so you will know if there are any differences.

Answer (score 0):

Excel files with the extension `xlsx` (note the 'x' at the end) are actually `zip` files with `xml` documents inside.  If you add data to the end of the file, you invalidate the zip so Excel can't open it.

It looks like your function may not be deleting the added text properly.  You could try opening the original file and the new file in a hex comparison program to see what is different about them.  Additionally, you can rename the file to ".zip" to see if it opens in a zip program.